# Turn off Reactable's fade effect on table

Tags: r, reactable

I've got a table in R Studio using Reactable to format it. When my cursor isn't resting on the table, it has a faded out effect. How do I remove this effect so I get the sharper colours without hovering?

Orange boxes on the below screenshots are to hide sensitive information only.

Without cursor on the table:
[image: Without cursor on the table:]

With cursor on the table:
[image: With cursor on the table:]

```
colnames(kpi_data_non_vip_formatted) <- c("Measure","brand_ly","brand_ty","brand_diff","brand_diff_pct","index_ly","index_ty","index_diff","index_diff_pct")

reactable(kpi_data_non_vip_formatted,
          defaultColDef = colDef(
              align = "center",
              minWidth = 70
            ),
          columns = list(
            "brand_ly" = colDef(name="LY"),
            "brand_ty" = colDef(name="TY"),
            "brand_diff" = colDef(name="Difference"),
            "brand_diff_pct" = colDef(name="Difference %"),
            "index_ly" = colDef(name="LY"),
            "index_ty" = colDef(name="TY"),
            "index_diff" = colDef(name="Difference"),
            "index_diff_pct" = colDef(name="Difference %")
          ),
          columnGroups=list(
            colGroup(name=brand_label, columns=c("brand_ly","brand_ty","brand_diff","brand_diff_pct")),
            colGroup(name=index_label, columns=c("index_ly","index_ty","index_diff","index_diff_pct"))
            #,style=list(backgroundColor=dark_green)
          ),
          theme = reactableTheme(
            backgroundColor=background_colour,
            style = list(fontFamily = "TT Commons Pro"),
            groupHeaderStyle = list(color=background_colour,backgroundColor=dark_green),
            headerStyle = list(color=background_colour,backgroundColor=mid_teal)
          )
)
```